# How do I make my fixed background responsive?

Tags: html, css, background, responsive, fixed

I want my background to take up all the space on the ipad views when making my webpage responsive. It works fine for mobile phones but with tablets it cuts off and the image won't take up the entire space. I think it may have something to do with me having one of my media queries set at a max width of 1024px but I don't know I am new to responsive design plus it says I need to type more details. Hopefully all of this makes sense.

```
<body>
            <div class="bg"></div>
        <header>
            <section class="title">
                <div class="title__step2">
                    <h1 class="title__head">Step 2</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>
                        Choose your City
                    </h1>
                    <p>Welcome to Step Number 2! You're almost there, just tell us which city you are interested in moving to and we can make it happen!</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </header>
        </body>

    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        background:url(https://www.metrojourneys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/guatape-antioquia-colombia.jpg);
        margin: 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 95vh;
    }
    
    :root {
        --main-color: rgba(255, 111, 15, 0.8)
        
    }
    
    .title {
        margin-top: 2.5%;
        margin-left: 12.5%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 75%;
        background: var(--main-color);
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    
    .title__head {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        background: white;
        color:  var(--main-color);
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    .bg {
    background:url(https://www.metrojourneys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/guatape-antioquia-colombia.jpg);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    }
    

    .title {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        width: 21.5rem;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 21.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 4px black solid;
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
    
    

    @media only screen and (min-width: 660px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .bg {
            background:url(https://www.metrojourneys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/guatape-antioquia-colombia.jpg);
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: try to remove the height and add `background-attachment : fixed`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you are looking for :

First : Delete your .bg element from your html and css(you won't need it)

Then :
replace :

```
body {
    background:url(https://www.metrojourneys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/guatape-antioquia-colombia.jpg);
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 95vh;
}
```

with :

```
html{
    background:url(https://www.metrojourneys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/guatape-antioquia-colombia.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```